# Why does Puppeeteer cause my test suite to hang for 30 seconds when I use "waitForSelector" even though I'm calling "close" on the page and browser?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a Node.js Mocha test suite (I've created a minimal reproduction based on the real world application I was trying to create an automated test for).

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "puppeteer-mocha-hang-repro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "4.3.7",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "mocha": "10.2.0",
    "puppeteer": "19.6.2"
  }
}
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const webServerPort = 3001;

describe('test suite', function () {
    this.timeout(10000);

    let webServer;
    let browser;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        // Start web server using Express
        const app = express();
        app.get('/', (_, res) => {
            res.send('<html>Hello, World from the <span id="source">Express web server</span>!</html>');
        });
        webServer = app.listen(webServerPort, () => {
            console.log(`Web server listening on port ${webServerPort}.`);
        });

        // Start browser using Puppeteer
        browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        console.log('Browser launched.');
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        // Stop browser
        await browser.close();
        console.log('Browser closed.');

        // Stop web server
        await webServer.close();
        console.log('Web server closed.');
    });

    it('should work', async () => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(`http://localhost:${webServerPort}/`);
        console.log('Went to root page of web server via Puppeteer.');

        if (process.env['PARSE_PAGE'] === 'true') {
            const sel = await page.waitForSelector('#source');
            const text = await sel.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
            console.log('According to Puppeteer, the text content of the #source element on the page is:', text);
            expect(text).eql('Express web server');
        }

        await page.close();
        console.log('Page closed.');
    });
});
```

If I run the test suite with the command `npx mocha index.spec.js`, which causes lines 45-48 to be skipped, the test suite passes and the Mocha process ends quickly:

```
$ time npx mocha index.spec.js


  test suite
Web server listening on port 3001.
Browser launched.
Went to root page of web server via Puppeteer.
Page closed.
    ✔ should work (70ms)
Browser closed.
Web server closed.


  1 passing (231ms)


real    0m0.679s
user    0m0.476s
sys     0m0.159s
```

Note that it finished in 0.679s.

If I instead run it with the command `PARSE_PAGE=true npx mocha index.spec.js`, which causes none of my code to be skipped, the tests pass quickly but the process hangs for about 30 seconds:

```
$ time PARSE_PAGE=true npx mocha index.spec.js


  test suite
Web server listening on port 3001.
Browser launched.
Went to root page of web server via Puppeteer.
According to Puppeteer, the text content of the #source element on the page is: Express web server
Page closed.
    ✔ should work (79ms)
Browser closed.
Web server closed.


  1 passing (236ms)


real    0m30.631s
user    0m0.582s
sys     0m0.164s
```

Note that it finished in 30.631s.

I suspected that this meant I was leaving things open, forgetting to call functions like `close`. But, I am calling `close` on the Express web server, Puppeteer browser, and Puppeteer page. I tried calling `close` on the objects I use when I don't skip any of that code, which are `sel` and `text`. But if I try that, I get error messages telling me that those objects have no such functions.

System details:

```
$ node --version
v18.13.0
$ npm --version
9.4.0
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
$ uname -r
5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL
```

Comment: add some print statement to figure out which function is slow.

Comment: My code already has `console.log` statements after each operation that does anything significant. The final one is "Web server closed." which is printed after the Express web server is closed in the `afterEach` hook. I understand this to mean each of the functions I defined in my code completed quickly (the `beforeEach` hook, the `afterEach` hook, my `it` test, and my `describe` suite).

Comment: is there a 30 second delay or do they all print quickly?

Comment: All of the `console.log` lines in my code print quickly. It just takes about 30 seconds for the entire Mocha process to end (at which point it ends with status code 0).

Comment: try providing a timeout here:             `const sel = await page.waitForSelector('#source');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: this behavior is a regression fixed by [#9612](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/9612) and deployed as [19.6.3](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/puppeteer-v19.6.3). To fix the problem, upgrade to 19.6.3 (or downgrade to <= 19.6.0 if you're using an older Puppeteer for some reason).

See the original answer below.

---

I'm able to reproduce the hang, even without Mocha. It seems to be a bug in Puppeteer versions 19.6.1 and 19.6.2. Here's a minimal example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // 19.6.1 or 19.6.2

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>hi</p></body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const el = await page.waitForSelector("p");
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(async () => {
    await browser?.close();
    console.log("browser closed");
  });
```

The culprit is `page.waitForSelector`, which seems to run its full 30 second default timeout even after resolving, somehow preventing the process from exiting. I've opened [issue #9610](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9610) on Puppeteer's GitHub repo.

Possible workarounds:

- Downgrade to 19.6.0.
- Avoid using `waitForSelector`, since the data you want is in the static HTML (may not apply to your actual page though).
- Call with `page.waitForSelector("#source", {timeout: 0})` which seems to fix the problem, with the risk of stalling forever if used in a script (not a problem with mocha since the test will time out).
- Call with `page.waitForSelector("#source", {timeout: 1000})` which reduces the impact of the delay, with the risk of a false positive if the element takes longer than a second to load. This doesn't seem to stack, so if you use a 1-3 second delay across many tests, mocha should exit within a few seconds of all tests completing rather than the sum of all delays across all `waitForSelector` calls. This isn't practical in most scripts, though.
- Run `npx mocha --exit index.spec.js`. Not recommended--this suppresses the issue.

I'm not sure if the behavior is specific to `waitForTimeout` or if it may apply to other `waitFor`-family methods.

As an aside, your server listen and close calls are technically race conditions, so:

```js
await new Promise(resolve =>
  webServer = app.listen(webServerPort, () => {
    console.log(`Web server listening on port ${webServerPort}.`);
    resolve();
  })
);
```

and

```js
await new Promise(resolve => webServer.close(() => resolve()));
```

---

System details:

```
$ node --version
v18.7.0
$ npm --version
9.3.0
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
$ uname -r
5.15.0-56-generic
```

I also confirmed the behavior on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for trying my code and reproducing the hang. Your suggestion to use the static HTML of the page won't work when I get past this issue though, because in my case, this is just a minimal reproduction for the purpose of posting this to Stack Overflow, and later I'll be using the DOM a lot more, waiting for events etc, to create a test suite for my actual applications (which include a back end Express server, a front end SPA, and a 3rd party server that both the back end and front end interact with).

Comment: I'm going to try your other suggestions later when I have time to try to sort out whether I'm not calling `waitForSelector` properly, etc. And then I can create a bug report if I conclude I'm using the library correctly and think it's a bug with the library.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in the post. It's one of four suggestions, only added for completeness for use cases that don't need to wait. You can ignore it if that option doesn't apply to you. The `{timeout: 0}` option is the primary suggestion I'm offering here, for the time being. Curious to hear how it goes for you and happy to see a link to an issue if you do open one up.

Comment: I looked into it a bit more. Downgrading to 19.6.0 fixes the issue for me, so that's my current recommendation. I opened a [GH issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9610).

Comment: Thanks. That's going to be my course of action for now. I'll accept this answer since there is no solution and we need a bug fix to be issued.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the super clear question. I wonder if the problem is [this change in `WaitTask`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/compare/puppeteer-v19.6.0...puppeteer-v19.6.1#diff-31c63819ab9b8669b18bb453b121974efd8e3bd0c4dc0ada8b241b2276e9d2ffR174) which guards the `clearTimeout` more strictly?

Comment: That seems to be it. I opened a [PR](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/9612) so it should be resolved next version.

Comment: 19.6.3 is deployed with the fix.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how much it will be helpful but you can try this:

```
if (process.env['PARSE_PAGE'] === 'true') {
   const sel = await page.waitForSelector('#source');
   const text = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, sel);
   console.log('According to Puppeteer, the text content of the #source element on the page is:', text);
   expect(text).eql('Express web server');
}
```

Also, check for global hooks!

Comment: This didn't help. Can you clarify what you mean by global hooks? Are you referring to something specific to either Puppeteer or Mocha, or Node.js in general?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Puppeteer but used Playwright for some time. In Playwright, you can create global-setup.js/ts file to configure pre and after test actions.

Comment: Also, try to close the browser after all tests. That may save you some time. Bcoz, you won't have to re-open the browser for each test. You will just continue testing on the same browser that was initially opened.

Comment: Nothing in this answer accurately identifies the problem or offers a solution to it, just shuffles syntax around a bit. Global setup and using one browser across multiple tests are nice suggestions but totally unrelated to the problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion to re-use the browser in multiple tests. It could be helpful for anyone coming across this question. In my case, I specifically used a fresh browser for each test because in my mind, that eliminated another class of problems (re-used browser state). My goal posting this was to have a minimal reproduction. My goal later will be to optimize my test suite once I get past this problem.